# In Django forms I can't use regex validators

Tags: python, django, regex, django-forms

Good day. I want to use regex validator for my full_name field in Django 1.11.10. But when I run the below code it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

**forms.py**

```py
 class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['orderorbarcode'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
           self.fields['orderorbarcode'].label = "Order ID or Item Barcode"
           self.fields['full_name'].label = "Full Name"
           self.fields['phone_number'].label = "Phone Number"
           self.fields['full_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*required'})
           self.fields['email'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*required'})
           self.fields['phone_number'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*required'})
    
    
        class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = (
            'orderorbarcode','full_name','company','email',
            'phone_number','note')
    
   
    
            AlphanumericValidator = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    
            full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[AlphanumericValidator])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the validator in models instead of forms (if `full_name` is a field model field):

```py
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

validate_alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_alphanumeric])
```

OR in your model:

```py
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # form field moved to the top (instead of being after Meta class)
    AlphanumericValidator = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[AlphanumericValidator])    
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # code

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
        'orderorbarcode','full_name','company','email',
        'phone_number','note')
```